# Spark dataframe : Is it more efficient to filter during a join or after?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, join, apache-spark-sql

I'm having some trouble finding an answer for this question, so I was wondering if someone could help me there.

Here's some context :

I have two dataframe df1 and df2 :

```
val df1: DataFrame = List((1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 3)).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
val df2: DataFrame = List((1, 5, 6), (1, 2, 5)).toDF("col1", "col2_bis", "col3_bis")
```

What I would like to do is

> join those dataframes df1 and df2 on "col1", but only keeping the rows where
>   df1("col2") < df2("col2_bis")

So my question is, is it more efficient to do it like that :

```
df1.join(df2, df1("col1") === df2("col1") and df1("col2") < df2("col2_bis"), "inner")
```

or like that :

```
df1.join(df2, Seq("col1"), "inner").filter(col("col2") < col("col2_bis"))
```

The result would be :

```
Array(Row(1, 2, 3, 5, 6)) with columns ("col1", "col2", "col2_bis", "col3", "col3_bis")
```

Are those two expressions resolved to the same execution plan? or is one of them more time-efficient than the other?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just checking the execution plan of both approaches..?

Comment: Thats...a good idea, can't believe I never actually thought of doing that. Thanks!

Comment: If one of your Dataframes is small enough for memory, you can do a "map-side join", which allows you to join and filter simultaneously by doing only a `.map` which contains a lookup against a local copy of the smaller table.

Answer (score 7):

If you look at the query plan, both are same, there is no difference with the join. The catalyst optimizer does all kinds of optimizations under the hood.

```
scala> val df2 = List((1, 5, 6), (1, 2, 5)).toDF("col1", "col2_bis", "col3_bis")
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: int, col2_bis: int ... 1 more field]

scala> val df1 = List((1, 2, 3), (2, 3, 3)).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
df1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: int, col2: int ... 1 more field]

scala> df1.join(df2, df1("col1") === df2("col1") and df1("col2") < df2("col2_bis"), "inner")
res0: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: int, col2: int ... 4 more fields]

scala> df1.join(df2, Seq("col1"), "inner").filter(col("col2") < col("col2_bis"))
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [col1: int, col2: int ... 3 more fields]

scala> res0.show
+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+
|col1|col2|col3|col1|col2_bis|col3_bis|
+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+
|   1|   2|   3|   1|       5|       6|
+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+

scala> res1.show
+----+----+----+--------+--------+
|col1|col2|col3|col2_bis|col3_bis|
+----+----+----+--------+--------+
|   1|   2|   3|       5|       6|
+----+----+----+--------+--------+

scala> res0.explain
== Physical Plan ==
*BroadcastHashJoin [col1#21], [col1#7], Inner, BuildRight, (col2#22 < col2_bis#8)
:- LocalTableScan [col1#21, col2#22, col3#23]
+- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, int, false] as bigint)))
   +- LocalTableScan [col1#7, col2_bis#8, col3_bis#9]

scala> res1.explain
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [col1#21, col2#22, col3#23, col2_bis#8, col3_bis#9]
+- *BroadcastHashJoin [col1#21], [col1#7], Inner, BuildRight, (col2#22 < col2_bis#8)
   :- LocalTableScan [col1#21, col2#22, col3#23]
   +- BroadcastExchange HashedRelationBroadcastMode(List(cast(input[0, int, false] as bigint)))
      +- LocalTableScan [col1#7, col2_bis#8, col3_bis#9]
```